# iOS : Colorize only the black part of an image

Tags: ios, core-graphics

quick question : I usually colorize my images, but they are only black and white image masks. I now have an image with a transparent background, a black part and other parts that are already colorized.

Is there a way to programmatically colorize only the black part of the image? I tried several kCGBlendMode, but none worked. I wonder if I have a to create a new image, use it as a mask for the colorized parts and then programmatically colorize the rest of the image.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this simply? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at CIFilter. There are loads of filters. Can't look up atm but you will be able to get one that converts black to a different colour. Use it to turn your image into a filtered image and then display the filtered image instead. It's fast too.

Answer (score 0):

take a look this solution: there is not bad example how to make a mask any shape with a black and white image

https://github.com/NickTitle/iOS7-Trans-Blur/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks, but it is only for black and white images. That I can handle. It is for already colorized images with black parts that I'm stucked ;)